# How to set label to each widget in django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter?

Tags: django, django-filters

How can I set label 'Start date' to widget[0] and 'End Date' to widget[1] in DateFromToRangeFilter?

```
class CasesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    datelastupdate=DateTimeFromToRangeFilter()
    testtime=DateTimeFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:SS'}))
    class Meta:
        model = ListOfCases
        fields=['id_test' ,
                'datelastupdate',
                'testtime',
                'active_flag',
                'version'
        ]
```